# prevent jquery ready on back button

Tags: jquery

I have a website which has an enormously long index. I use jQuery to hide all nested items and an only show the major categories when the page loads.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
  $('div.sideNav li > ul').css({"display":"none"}); //hide all nested ul's
});
```

I have another script to expand and collapse the index category items as a user clicks on them.

But inside the categories are links to actual documents which are pdfs. So if someone clicks on a pdf to view it, it navigates to a new pages. Then when they are done viewing it, they hit the back button and they want to see the index expanded the way it was before they left so that they can continue browsing the index.

Right now the ready function is getting called when the page comes back from the pdf and collapses the index back to its initial state. How can I prevent this so that the nested list items only hide when the page loads?

Comment: I would have the pdf's open in another window.

Answer (score 5):

I think simplest solution would be to open the PDF in a new window using `target="_blank"`:

```
<a href="pdf-path-here" target="_blank">View PDF</a>
```

This way the user will close the new tab, and the page will be as it was previous.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of worrying about how to handle if someone clicks the back button, I would suggest you just open the PDF in a new window.  This will allow the user to close the PDF directly and then you dont have to worry about preserving the previous page's state.

You will want to use the `target` attribute if you are not sure how to spawn a new window when clicking a link:

```
<a href="pdf-link" target="_blank">Open PDF</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I thought about using target blank but wondered if there might be some other jQuery event to use instead of ready().

Comment: No need for jQuery, when this is what you're wanting.  Can it be done in jQuery, yes, but why make a solution more complex than it has to be. Read up on [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) if you're not familiar.

Answer (score 2):

Use cookies or localStorage to store data on the way the index is expanded and when `jQuery(document).ready()` is called, read the data stored in them to determine which items to expand. When a visitor clicks on a link, and goes back, the page loads again, data is lost unless it is saved.

EDIT: If you want them to open the links in the same tab or window, that is